# Does Induction Work Well with Augmentation Ideals?

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $\Sigma_n$ be the $n$th symmetric group.  Then the complex representation ring $R\Sigma_n$ has the augmentation ideal $I_n$, with the $k$th power ideal $I_n^k$.  Since $\Sigma_n\times\Sigma_m\leq \Sigma_{n+m}$ we have an induction map

$$
\operatorname{Ind}: R[\Sigma_n\times\Sigma_m]\longrightarrow R\Sigma_{n+m}
$$

given by taking $M\in R\Sigma_n$ and $N\in R\Sigma_m$ and inducing up $M\otimes N$.  Suppose $M\in I_n^k$ and $N\in I_m^l$.  Then the induced module is isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of $M\otimes N$ with an induced action.  Therefore the induced module still has virtual dimension 0.  My question is whether $\operatorname{Ind}(M\otimes N)\in I_{n+m}^{k+l}$.

Comment: Very interesting question, but please: it's "$k$-th power ideal", not "ideal of $k$-th powers".

Comment: What is virtual dimension?

Also, when you write $M \in R\Sigma_n$, I assume you mean that $M$ is an $R\Sigma_n$-module, and when you write $M \in I_n^k$, you mean that $M$ is an $R\Sigma_n$-submodule of $I_n^k$.

Comment: @Chris:  The elements of the augmentation ideal are those that map to 0 under the dimension homomorphism.  I say virtual dimension 0 since they are not representations.  By $M\in R\Sigma_n$ I mean $M$ is in the Grothendieck group generated by the complex representations of $\Sigma_n$.  By $M\in I_n^k$, I mean that $M$ is an element of the $k$th power ideal of $R\Sigma_n$.

Comment: @Joe I see, I misinterpreted the Grothendieck ring for the group ring.